# Determining if the user is speaking on a HL2

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I've been using the MRTK MicStream APIs to try to merely determine if the HoloLens 2 user is speaking. I've tried for a couple of weeks. All attempts have failed for reasons documented [here](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/9717) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73704875/issue-accessing-hololens-2-audio-data-using-microsoft-windowsmicrophonestream?noredirect=1#comment130169409_73704875). I am officially giving up on the MicStream API, and also tried the AudioFrame method from the MediaCapture APIs which also fail. (MediaCapture is how the MicStream DLL also attempts to access raw audio data which you can see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit/blob/main/Input/MicStreamSelector/Source/MicStreamSelector.cpp), on line 351 - 357 so this isnt surprising).

My question is: how else can I determine only if a user is speaking?  I do not need dictation, a recording, or to use speech commands. I only want to know if the two user microphones on channel 1 and 2 are active above the normal room amplitude (in real time).  Does anyone know any other ways outside these methods?

Comment: Have you tried updating you motherboard drivers?  The stream isn't working with the codec on your motherboard.

Comment: I think I've further narrowed down the original problem. Its something to do with two MediaCapture objects running at the same time.  The first one (that always works and is initialized first) is created in the Awake function of my main script.  The second, the one intended for audio, is created by the MicStream DLL. As soon as the photo capture object pulls its first frame, the audio capture object quits working. I currently do not know why.

Comment: The photo capture tool may have an audio input and causes a conflict.  It also can be the motherboard drivers that have a bug.  Go to manufactures website and update.

Answer (score 1):

For what its worth - I finally fixed it. The MicStream DLL's MediaCapture instance was conflicting with one I had already instantiated for photo captures. In short, you cant use MicStream with another MediaCapture instance. I tried to set the settings for SharingMode on the first MediaCapture (in my script for capturing photos, but this didnt work.  I had to completely stop using the MicStream .dll and streamline the audio capture under one MediaCapture instantiated with StreamingCaptureMode.AudioAndVideo. This fixed the problem.